# compute determinant and is A invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Compute the determinant of

A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1+i & 2 \\ -2i & 0 & 1-i \\ 3 & 4i & 0 \end{bmatrix}

along the third row.

Is A invertible?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. The custom here is to post some effort that you've made toward solving the problem, so we can see exactly what is giving you trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're stating "along the 3rd row", I'll assume you want to use the method using the "submatrices" :

So we end up with :

$$(-1)^0\cdot3\cdot \det\left(\begin{bmatrix}1+i&2\\0&1-i\end{bmatrix}\right) + (-1)^1\cdot 4i \cdot \det\left(\begin{bmatrix}0&2\\-2i&1-i\end{bmatrix}\right) + (-1)^2\cdot 0 \cdot \det\left(\begin{bmatrix}0&i+1\\-2i&0\end{bmatrix}\right)$$
Which you should be able to process, since those are 2x2 matrices, and we get so :
 $$(-1)^0\cdot3\cdot (1-i^2) + (-1)^1\cdot 4i \cdot 4i + (-1)^2\cdot 0 \cdot (2i)(i+1)=3\cdot 2+16 = 22$$
Hence since it has a non-zero determinant, it is invertible.